# how many and how to divided in different parts of regions(Eden,Surviver,old Gen.) in G1 GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

What is the internal calculation of how many parts makes of Eden,survivor and old Gen in G1 GC.
And how to perform different type of GC(Minor,Major,Full) on G1 GC.

please anyone can describe in detail.

Comment: You should add some code, it will help to determine the problem